# create table and load data in redshift from Parquet file in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have my Parquet file in S3. I want to load this to the redshift table. I don't know the schema of the Parquet file.

Is there any command to create a table and then copy parquet data to it?

Also, I want to add the default time column `date timestamp DEFAULT to_char(CURRDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')`.

Comment: Start from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52194599/load-parquet-files-into-redshift

Answer (score -1):

You need first to create an external schema. Normal colunar schemas do not support parquet files.
Them you need to create a external table to support the columns on the s3 file. So look for a good relation between the file and datatypes. I usually avoid smalls ints for example. To floats create as REAL data type.
Then, do the copy command bellow:

```
COPY schema_name.table_name 
FROM bucket_object iam_role user_arn 
FORMAT PARQUET;
```